# writing systemd unit file and specfile for a python twistd application

Tags: python, rpmbuild, systemd, twistd, rpm-spec

I have given a task to write the systemd unit file for a python twistd application and create rpm of it. The application is open source and you can find it [here](https://github.com/ecmanaged/ecm-agent).

I have written the unit file as:

```
[Unit]
Description=ECManaged Agent for monitoring and deployment
[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/twistd.pid
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/twistd -y /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/ecagentd.tac
ExecStart=\
/bin/twistd \
--nodaemon \
--pidfile=/opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/twistd.pid \
--no_save \
--python=/opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/ecagentd.tac
WorkingDirectory=/opt/ecmanaged/ecagent
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have written the rpmbuild specfile as:

```
%define name      ecmanaged-ecagent
%define ename     ecagentd
%define pname     ecmanaged

Name:           %{name}
Version:        2.1.2       
Release:        109%{?el#}
Summary:        ECManaged  Agent - Monitoring and deployment agent
Group:          Applications/System
License:        GPLv3+
URL:            www.ecmanaged.com
Source0:        ecmanaged-ecagent.tar.gz
BuildArch:      noarch

Requires:       python2
Requires:       python-twisted-core
Requires:       python-twisted-web
Requires:       python-protocols
Requires:       python-configobj
Requires:       python-twisted-words
Requires:       python-psutil
Requires:       libxml2-python
Requires:       python-simplejson
Requires:       rpm-python
Requires:       python-crypto
Requires:       python-httplib2

BuildRequires:      systemd

Provides:       ecmanaged-ecagent

%description
ECManaged  Agent - Monitoring and deployment agent

%prep
%setup -qn %{name}

%build


%install

rm -rf %{buildroot}

mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt//ecmanaged/ecagent
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/rc.d/init.d
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/etc/cron.d
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/

rsync -av --exclude '*build*' %{_builddir}/%{name}/* %{buildroot}/opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/
install -m 750 %{_builddir}/%{name}/build/redhat/etc/init.d/ecagentd %{buildroot}/etc/rc.d/init.d
install -m 644 %{_builddir}/%{name}/build/redhat/etc/cron.d/ecmanaged-ecagent $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/cron.d

cp %{_builddir}/%{name}/build/redhat/etc/systemd/system/ecagentd.service %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/


rm -rf %{_builddir}/%{name}/build

%clean
#rm -rf %{_buildroot}%{name}
#rm -rf %{_source_path}%{name}

%post
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable ecagentd.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start ecagentd.service >/dev/null 2>&1

%preun
systemctl stop ecagentd.service >/dev/null 2>&1
systemctl disable ecagentd.service
systemctl daemon-reload

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%attr(750,root,root) /etc/rc.d/init.d/ecagentd
%attr(750,root,root) /usr/lib/systemd/system/ecagentd.service
%attr(644,root,root) /etc/cron.d/ecmanaged-ecagent
%attr(755,root,root) /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/
%attr(700,root,root) %config /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/config
%attr(400,root,root) %config /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/config/ecagent.init.cfg
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/plugins/*.pyc
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/plugins/*.pyo
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/examples/*.pyc
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/examples/*.pyo
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/ecagent/*.pyc
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/ecagent/*.pyo
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/ecagent/*.pyc
%exclude /opt/ecmanaged/ecagent/ecagent/*.pyo

%changelog
```

I know its a bit weird that the application does not use setuptools.

They also have a [init.d script](https://github.com/ecmanaged/ecm-agent/blob/master/build/redhat/etc/init.d/ecagentd) and a [cron job](https://github.com/ecmanaged/ecm-agent/blob/master/build/redhat/etc/cron.d/ecmanaged-ecagent) which uses it. you can find them using the links.

Are they safe to remove? if yes, how?

Am I doing it well? How can I make it better? any pointer and suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point of using PIDFile in your service file as you are using type as simple.

PIDFile is only useful when your service type is forking (as follows):

```
[Service]
Type=forking
```